# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, debian, socket

The IP address on my server recently was changed, and after the change, i performed a restart and when it came back online MySQL stopped working. I am running Debian 6.

I type mysql -u username -p and I get this message:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

any idea what happened? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When the server's IP was changed, the bind-address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf was still set to the old IP, which caused this problem.